# Is there a more rational way to replace all slashes using javascript than this?

Tags: javascript

```
var input = '/string/';
var output = input.replace(/\//g,'');
// requested output = 'string';
```

What I don't like about this method is that the double slashes might be considered a comment and ignored by certain browsers, or am I wrong?

It works in my browser, but I can't test in every browser. Is it a perfectly proper method, or is there a better solution?

Comment: If any browser considers `/\//g` as comment, then its JavaScript parser is very broken.

Comment: it will work in every browser that supports javascript with regular expression. Everything between two unquoted slashes will be handled as regular expression.

Comment: I think so too, the RegEx-Syntax shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I don't like about this method is that the double slashes might be considered a comment and ignored by certain browsers

What double slashes? The ones in the regexp? Certainly not, unless the browser's JavaScript parser is **totally broken.**

> Is it a perfectly proper method

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct way to do the replacement. The double slashes won't be interpreted as a comment by any production browser; that regex form is a valid part of EMCAScript.

Answer (score 2):

It should be alright but if you're really concerned, use a `RegExp` object, eg

```
var re = new RegExp("/", "g");
var output = input.replace(re, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the syntax is correct. It will work with any JavaScript engine.